# In Dart2, what is the correct "anything" type to use for generics?

Tags: dart

AngularDart has a class called `AppView`, i.e. `abstract class AppView<T> {}`.

One (at least) of these are generated for every class annotated with `@Component`:

```
// file.dart
@Component(...)
class DashboardComponent {}


// file.template.dart (Generated)
class ViewDashboardComponent extends AppView<DashboardComponent> {}
```

I have code elsewhere in the framework that doesn't care what this `T` type is. I'm a little confused with Dart 2 what the "right" "anything" type to use. For example, I could use:

- `AppView`
- `AppView<dynamic>`
- `AppView<Object>`
- `AppView<Null>`
- `AppView<void>`

I think more than one of these will "work". But which is the "right" one to use in this case?

Comment: Great question. One of the more confusing parts of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine to use `AppView` (or `AppView<dynamic>`) just about anywhere. I can think of two examples where this will get you into trouble though:

1. If you are *instantiating* an AppView, you definitely want that type parameter. See the following error when you don't:

   ```
   $ cat a.dart
   void main() {                                                                                                                          
     List<dynamic> a = ["one", "two", "three"];
     List<String> b = a;
   }
   $ dart --preview-dart-2 a.dart
   Unhandled exception:
   type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' where
     List is from dart:core
     List is from dart:core
     String is from dart:core

   #0      main (file:///Users/sam/a.dart:3:20)
   #1      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:279:19)
   #2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165:12)
   ```
2. If you are ever *assigning a closure* to a site that expects a closure with one or more typed parameters that involve T, you will see a "uses dynamic as bottom" static error (from the analyzer), and probably a runtime error as well:

   ```
   $ cat f.dart                                                       

   void main() {
     List a = <String>["one", "two", "three"];
     a.map((String s) => s.toUpperCase());

     List b = ["one", "two", "three"];
     b.map((String s) => s.toUpperCase());
   }
   $ dart --preview-dart-2 f.dart
   f.dart:3:9: Error: A value of type '(dart.core::String) → dart.core::String' can't be assigned to a variable of type '(dynamic) → dynamic'.
   Try changing the type of the left hand side, or casting the right hand side to '(dynamic) → dynamic'.
     a.map((String s) => s.toUpperCase());
           ^
   f.dart:6:9: Error: A value of type '(dart.core::String) → dart.core::String' can't be assigned to a variable of type '(dynamic) → dynamic'.
   Try changing the type of the left hand side, or casting the right hand side to '(dynamic) → dynamic'.
     b.map((String s) => s.toUpperCase());
           ^
   ```

(I'm not certain *any* Dart tool yet has complete Dart 2 runtime and compile time semantics, so this might change slightly.)

In these cases, it is best to use [generic classes](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics), [generic methods](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#using-generic-methods), and [generic typedefs](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/generic-function-type-alias.md) to encapsulate, for a given scope, what the values of an object's type parameters might be.

I suspect there is a difference between `dynamic` and `Object` in Dart 2, and I think Günter covered this in his response, though if your code "doesn't care what this T type is", then you're probably not calling any methods on the component.

### Edit: void

`AppView<void>` might be a good choice in this case, as an actual check that you *actually* never touch the underlying component (Object would probably serve the same purpose). See how we are allowed to access properties of a `List<void>` but not properties of the elements:

```
$ cat g.dart
void main() {
  var c = <String>["one", "two", "three"];
  fn(c);
  fn2(c);
}

int fn(List<void> list) => list.length;

int fn2(List<void> list) => list.first.length;
$ dart --preview-dart-2 g.dart
g.dart:9:40: Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'void'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.
int fn2(List<void> list) => list.first.length;
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know better than me, but my attempt

- `AppView` - works - same as `AppView<dynamic>`
- `AppView<dynamic>` - works - really means any type
- `AppView<Object>` - works - really means any type
- `AppView<Null>` - won't work, only `null` and `void` values match for `T`
- <strike>`AppView<void>` - won't work, only `null` and `void` values match for `T`</strike>
  `AppView<void>` - works (see also comment below from lrn)

The difference between `<dynamic>` and `<Object>` would be that for values of type `T` with `T` == `dynamic` property or method access won't be checked statically, while for `T` == `Object` only methods and properties of the `Object` class can be accessed without a previous cast.

Comment: `AppView<void>` should work. That change to make any value assignable to `void` is part of Dart 2, just as the ability to use `void` as a type argument at all. If it doesn't work, please file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I assumed that would only be for function return values.